Query json array inside json object in BigQuery
can you lend me a hand for the following query, first this is the data im using for learning (do not worry about its structure is just for learning how to query JSON), it is a simple cars table with a column called objeto which is a JSON that has a json object (person) and inside it an array attribute called cars:
INSERT INTO `project.dataset.cars`
  (id, color, objeto)
VALUES
  (1, 'Blue', JSON '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", JSON """{
  "person": {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "cars": [
      {
        "make": "Toyota",
        "model": "Camry"
      },
      {
        "make": "Honda",
        "model": "Civic"
      }
    ]
  }
}""");

I was looking at the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array with the objective of getting all "make" contained in array of my records, so I tried the following:
SELECT
  id,
  color,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(objeto.person.cars, '$.make') AS all_makes
FROM
  `project.dataset.cars`;

I get no errors but also no results in the all_makes, I know that you can get specific like this:
SELECT
  id,
  color,
  objeto.person.cars[0].make
FROM
  `project.dataset.cars`;

And this would return "Toyota" for the record I provided at the begining, but how to get both "Toyota" and "Honda" (all makes)?
Thanks

Generally these functions won't cause errors when they find no results (because they are for working with unstructured data, so can't assume regularity). $.make won't work because the make key is part of the structure of the array elements, not the top level structure. If you just use $ I think you'll get the whole array. You'd then want to use UNNEST to convert each element into a separate record. You can then extract make for each record separately.

with mydata as (select 1 as id, 'Blue' as color, JSON '{"person": {"id": 123, "name": "John Doe", "cars": [{"make": "Toyota", "model": "Camry"}, {"make": "Honda", "model": "Civic" }]}}' as objeto)
select 
  id, 
  color, 
  string_agg(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(all_cars,'$.make')) as all_makes
from mydata, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(objeto, '$.person.cars')) AS all_cars
group by 1, 2



Thanks, can you explain what is the string_agg for? Also the UNNEST function, will check that in the documentation but appreciate simple explanation too

You are welcome. UNNEST is required to be able to query array like a table. STRING_AGG with GROUP BY are used to concatenate multiple rows of "make" into a single string. Check out this stripped query to understand better: select id, color, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(all_cars,'$.make') as all_makes from mydata, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(objeto, '$.person.cars')) AS all_cars
